# Mouse wheel scrolling not working inside Google Chrome. But working in Firefox, any solution?

Tags: windows-xp, google-chrome, mouse

Scrolling with the mouse wheel is not working in Google Chrome (on Windows), but works fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer.

- **Chrome Version**: 9.0.597.15 dev
- **OS**: Windows XP

Comment: Star the issue if you want to get updates on this http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=66182

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the dev version you are using

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=66071

Answer (score 0):

Known issue. They are working on a fix:

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=12c855d7acb70049&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in dev release ( 9.0.597.16 dev ).

Comment: Ok I will check in office on Monday